# How to define a Click handler function for multiple elements at the same time

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I have many CSS divs of which I need to write onclick function of each, I want to write the Click function once and in that I want to tell the function if it is element `a` do 1 and if it is element `b` do 2.

may I know how to write the function in jQuery?

```
$('.gil_Ads_BlankDock1').click(function(){ 

       $('#gDescZone1').hide();
       $('#gDescZone2').hide();
       $('#descAd1').hide();
       $('#descAd2').hide();
       $('#descAd3').hide();
       $('#descAd4').hide();           
       $('#header').hide();
       $('#contentArea').hide();
       $('#marquee').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });

 $('.gil_Ads_BlankDock2').click(function(){ 

       $('#gDescZone1').hide();
       $('#gDescZone2').hide();
       $('#descAd1').hide();
       $('#descAd2').hide();
       $('#descAd3').hide();
       $('#descAd4').hide();           
       $('#header').hide();
       $('#contentArea').hide();
       $('#marquee').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });

 $('.gil_Ads_BlankDock3').click(function(){ 

       $('#gDescZone1').hide();
       $('#gDescZone2').hide();
       $('#descAd1').hide();
       $('#descAd2').hide();
       $('#descAd3').hide();
       $('#descAd4').hide();           
       $('#header').hide();
       $('#contentArea').hide();
       $('#marquee').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });
```

above given code is my few click function which i want to write in shot cut.

Comment: Have you never used the comma before in a CSS selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to all of the answers above. You can also maintain an array of all the selectors to hide if you can't rewrite your code:

```
var mult = ['#gDescZone1','#gDescZone2','#descAd1','#descAd2',
               '#descAd3','#descAd4','#header','#contentArea',"#marquee'];
$.each(mult,function(index,value){
  $(value).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.gil_Ads_BlankDock1, .gil_Ads_BlankDock2, .gil_Ads_BlankDock3').click(function(){ 

       $('#gDescZone1').hide();
       $('#gDescZone2').hide();
       $('#descAd1').hide();
       $('#descAd2').hide();
       $('#descAd3').hide();
       $('#descAd4').hide();           
       $('#header').hide();
       $('#contentArea').hide();
       $('#marquee').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });
```

Or, if you have a chance to refactor your markup, you can give your containers the same class, say "ads":

```
$('.ads').click(function(){ 

       $('#gDescZone1').hide();
       $('#gDescZone2').hide();
       $('#descAd1').hide();
       $('#descAd2').hide();
       $('#descAd3').hide();
       $('#descAd4').hide();           
       $('#header').hide();
       $('#contentArea').hide();
       $('#marquee').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });
```

You can also group your hide operations:

```
$('.ads').click(function(){ 
       $('#gDescZone1, #gDescZone2, #descAd1, #descAd2, #descAd3, \
          #descAd4, #header, #contentArea, #marquee').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });
```

Morover, you could give the elements that you hide the same class, say "hideable":

```
$('.ads').click(function(){ 
       $('.hideable').hide();           
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });
```

The last form would be the proper way to do this, if you have a chance to add these additional classes to your markup.

Comment: Now may i know how to refer a particular Item clicked in if else statement

Comment: `this` will give you the DOM element that was clicked. `$(this)` wraps it inside a jQuery object. You can then access attributes of the element with `$(this).attr("some-attribute")`. `this.id` gives you the element id. All this is fundamental, basic stuff that you're encouraged to read up on. If I were you, I would spend some time browsing the jQuery documentation online.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.gil_Ads_BlankDock1, .gil_Ads_BlankDock2, .gil_Ads_BlankDock3').click(function(){ 

       $('#gDescZone1, #gDescZone2, #descAd1, #descAd2, #descAd3, #descAd4, #header, #contentArea, #marquee').hide();
       $('#BottomDock').fadeIn();
 });
```

Write less, do more :)

Now if you just had a way to write less markup...

Comment: Thank you... Basically my divs are positioned at different dimentions so i used multiple docks and on each docks i need to show different data.. Thanks any ways... and did i need to refer particular item clicked in if else statement as e.target....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... but yes, you can use **event.target** to tell which of the items was clicked, just change **function()** to **function(event)**.

Comment: Before it comes to `event.target`, jQuery gives you the element as `this`.